# Integration And Substitution

Tags: calculus

While integrating the function $$\int \frac{x}{x^2+x+1}dx$$ can we make the Substitution $x^2=t$ and transform the integral into $$\int \frac{dt}{2(t+\sqrt{t}+1)}$$

Comment: Yes you may, but where does that lead you ?

Comment: But $x^2=t$ gives $x=+\sqrt{t}$ and $x=-\sqrt{t}$ so can we choose any one of them?

Comment: Who could forbid you to try the subsitution $x=-\sqrt t$ ? But where does that lead you ?

Comment: But $x=+\sqrt{t}$ will give the anti derivatives on the interval $[0, \infty)$ only

Comment: Hem, why don't you ask the right question in the post ?

Comment: Consider starting by completing the square in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make that substitution, but like Yves hinted, it wouldn't lead you to the solution.

Here's another hint - think about this equation $x = \frac{1}{2}\cdot(2x+1)-\frac{1}{2}$, and how you can apply it to the question in order to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Write the numerator as $$a\dfrac{d(x^2+x+1)}{dx}+b=2ax+a+b$$

So that $b+a=0\iff b=-a$

$2a=1\iff a=?$

For the second half, use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

$2x+1=\sqrt3\tan t$

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

Denominator: Complete the square;

$x^2+x+1=(x+1/2)^2+3/4$;

Set $y:= x+1/2$,  then the integral becomes

$\displaystyle{\int }\dfrac {y-1/2}{y^2+3/4}dy$.

Split into $2$ parts:

$\displaystyle {\int} \dfrac{y}{y^2+3/4}dy$ and

$ -(1/2)\displaystyle {\int}\dfrac{1}{y^2+3/4}dy.$